# elliptic differential equation, What's mean of "By applying this process successively to Br1 , Br2 , · ·"

Tags: general-topology

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoRYe.png)

All proof is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usyjI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQvRz.png)

corollary 3.6 is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTd7h.png)

Set B = $B_R$ and consider an increasing sequence $r_k$ → R. We fix a positive integer $k$ temporarily. For any $x \in B_{rk}$, set $$d_k,_s = \text{dist}(x,∂B_{rk}).$$Then, $d_k,_x$ ≤ $d_x$ for any x ∈ $B_{rk}$. Moreover, we have f ∈ $C^α$($B_{rk}$) and |f|$C^α$($B_{rk}$) < ∞. Let $u_k$ ∈ C($B_{rk}$) ∩ $C^{2,α}$($B_{rk}$) be the solution of $$\triangle u_k = f\quad in\,B_{rk}$$$$\quad \,\,\,\,u_k = 0\quad on\,\partial B_{rk}$$Then for any m ≥ k,$$\triangle u_m = f\quad in\,B_{rk}$$By Corollary 3.6, a subsequence of {$u_m$ : m ≥ k} is convergent in $C^2$ in any compact subsets of $B_{rk}$. \ \ \***

1. By applying this process successively to $B_{r1}$, $B_{r2}$, · · · ,
   we conclude that a subsequence of {$u_m$} converges to a u ∈
   $C^{2,α}(B_R)$ in $C^2$ in any compact subsets of $B_R$.

*** Then, ∆u = f in $B_R$ and, for any x ∈ BR,$$d^
{−β}_x|u(x)| ≤ C sup_{x∈B_R}\,d^{2−β}_x|f(x)|.$$Therefore, u can be extended continuously to $∂B_R$ with u = 0 on $∂B_R$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: And please present your question clearly in your post.

Comment: More evidence of SEbots.